# Angular deployment with no .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a site, but the server this need deploying on can't have an .htaccess file. On our test server we have the following as the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

How can we remove the need for the htaccess? It's fine to have the # in the URL if this is the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way so posting the answer to help anyone with the same issue.

The index.html page was loading but all the assets, css and js files were 404ing, when building for production you can add a base-href which I added and pointed to the directory in the server.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /path/to/site/root/
```

This then worked, the only other thing I had to change was I was referencing some assets like this:

```
/assets/images/logo.png
```

Which I had to change to this for the base href to then work:

```
./assets/images/logo.png
```

Everything is working as I want it now without any .htaccess

The other thing to note is that without an .htaccess file the site will only work with the useHash enabled.